# Multiple drop-down menus per button group?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3

Right now I have this coming out on the interface:

[image: breaks between buttons]

But between the buttons with the `bolt`, `plus-circle` and `gear` I would like no gap. I have the gaps there because it seems like it is mandatory, per this comment in the Bootstrap Components docs:

> Use any button to trigger a dropdown menu by placing it within a .btn-group and providing the proper menu markup.

So, right now the gap is there because the buttons are laid out with a format of:

```
<div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
        <button type="button" title="Focusing" ... >
            <span class='fa fa-bolt '></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
            <span class='fa fa-plus-circle '></span>
            <span class='fa fa-caret-down '></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            ...
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
            <span class='fa fa-gear '></span>
            <span class='fa fa-caret-down '></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            ...
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

#### Is it possible to have more than one drop-down per button group?

If so, how would I do that? As it stands, it seems like I can place individual buttons ahead of a drop-down menu, but not multiple drop-down menus.

If I put multiple drop-down menus in the same button group, they all fire when one is clicked.

Comment: The spaces are likely caused by the DIV around each button group. Not sure about part 2 of your question though.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This is possible, you must wrap each dropdown button in another `.btn-group` div (without using `.btn-toolbar`) :

```
<div class="btn-group">

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-flash"></i>
  </button>

  <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i> <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i> <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

[**Bootply**](http://bootply.com/113314)

[**Documentation**](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups-nested)

Comment: Thanks for the bootply as well as code posted here. This solved my issue very well. I appreciate it a lot.

Comment: The issue I have with this solution is the dropdown event doesn't appear to work in IE.

Comment: Thanks, the problem i was facing was that the dropdown list was flying to the far left, instead of staying below it. This helped me.