# Updating dropdown value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement a dropdown time selector using Bootstrap:

[image]

HTML

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <a id="from-text" class="btn btn-default">From</a>
    <a
        data-target="#"
        class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"
        data-toggle="dropdown">
        <span
            class="caret">
        </span>
    </a>
    <ul id="from" class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">10:00 AM</a></li>
    </ul>

    <a id="to-text" class="btn btn-default">To</a>
    <a data-target="#" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul id="to" class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">10:00 AM</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
    $('#from li').on('click', function(){
        $('#from-text').val($(this).text());
    });

    $('#to li').on('click', function(){
        $('#to-text').val($(this).text());
    });
```

I am trying to select the time and then update the dropdown value to represent that time. Using the above code, when I click the dropdown value, it does not indeed update the text. No errors were found in the console either.

Comment: There's no `#datebox` element in your HTML.

Comment: @Amit updated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attach the event on <a> element.

JavaScript:

```
$('#from li a').on('click', function(){
    $('#datebox').text($(this).text());
});

$('#to li a').on('click', function(){
    $('#datebox').text($(this).text());
});
```

You can have two dropdowns in different .btn-group divs.

HTML:

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <a id="from-text" class="btn btn-default">From</a>
    <a
        data-target="#"
        class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"
        data-toggle="dropdown">
        <span
            class="caret">
        </span>
    </a>
    <ul id="from" class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">10:00 AM</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="btn-group">
    <a id="to-text" class="btn btn-default">To</a>
    <a data-target="#" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul id="to" class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">10:00 AM</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I added this to my JS code. Reloaded the page. Clicked the dropdown, however, the text remained "From" and "To".

Comment: I replaced `.val` with `.text` and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, what's happening with this is, when I click on the caret for `from` and pick a value, it updates the `to` text instead. Any ideas why?

Comment: You need to wrap each dropdown in different .btn-group. Edited the answer.

Comment: This worked. The reason I had it in the same button group was so that there would be no gap between the two buttons. This works, but it adds a gap between the two buttons. I guess I'll have to live with that.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21739236/multiple-drop-down-menus-per-button-group

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace the text inside an element, use `text(newText)`.

```
$('#from-text').text($(this).text());
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing the ID for the element in your HTML. Where ever you want to add the value for datebox give it an id="datebox"

but right now your code is going to update the same box value so you might want to change the id names so one is getting the value from "From" and the other to "TO"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to entirely replace the text use the `text()` function rather than `val()`.

```
$('#from li').on('click', function(){
    $('#from-text').text("from " + $(this).text());
});

$('#to li').on('click', function(){
    $('#to-text').text("to " + $(this).text());
});
```

Comment: What's happening with this is, when I click on the caret for `from` and pick a value, it updates the `to` text instead. Any ideas why?

Comment: You have to put div's around each dropdown. You will probably have to tinker with the css to get it to look right though but the js part will work.