# How to use multiple dropdowns in navbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navbar with icons and I want that 2 icons have a seperate dropdown menu. This is my code:

```
<div class="master-menu-right-wrapper">
    <div class="master-menu-right-item"><i class="icon-notifcation"></i></div>
    <div class="master-menu-right-item" id="add-menu" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="icon-add"></i></div>

    //this is not working
    <div class="dropdown-menu master-menu-dropdown" aria-labelledby="add-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">New member</a>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">New admin</a>
    </div> //this is not working

    <div class="master-menu-right-item"><i class="icon-setting"></i></div>
    <div class="master-menu-right-item master-menu-right-user">
        <div class="master-menu-right-user-font">Username</div>
    </div>
    <div class="master-menu-right-item" id="app-menu" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="icon-user"></i></div>
    //works
    <div class="dropdown-menu master-menu-dropdown" aria-labelledby="app-menu">
        <label>Welcome</label>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">App 1</a>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mr-5">Save</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Edit profile</button>
        </div>
        //works
    </div>
</div>
```

When I add one drop down its works when I click on the **user icon**. When I add second drop down it wil overwrite the previous one and I don't get two separate drop downs.

NOTE

I don't want a nested drop menu or multi level. Just 2 separate drop downs for each icon.

I have tried this solution:

[Multiple drop-down menus per button group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21739236/multiple-drop-down-menus-per-button-group)

This doesn't work for me because the styling will mess up.

How can I have two drop down menu for each icon?

UPDATE:

[image]

UPDATE:

CSS code:

```
 .master-menu-right-wrapper {
            float: right;
            width: auto;
            text-align: right;
            cursor: pointer;
            user-select: none;
        }

        .master-menu-right-item {
            display: inline-block;
            padding-top: 4px;
            height: 48px;
            font-size: 1.6rem;
            text-align: center;
        }


        .master-menu-right-user-font {
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 1rem;
        }

        .master-menu-right-user {
            margin-top: -10px;
            padding-left: 10px;
            border-left: thin solid #041348;
        }
```

Comment: Can you show a screenshot or code snippet we could run? Thanks.

Comment: I have draw a sketch

Comment: It seems that most of the css classes there such as .master-menu-right-wrapper, and etc are not bootstrap default. We might need a running snippet to help you further.

Comment: I have share my css code in the mean time I try to make a snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap each button/dropdown set in a div with class `btn-group`. That will allow Bootstrap to associate the button with the dropdown.

(The snippet is a bit janky shoehorned into a tiny window. But hopefully with the JS working, you can fix that up with styles.)

```css
.master-menu-right-wrapper {
  float: right;
  width: auto;
  text-align: right;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

.master-menu-right-item {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 4px;
  height: 48px;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  text-align: center;
}


.master-menu-right-user-font {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.master-menu-right-user {
  margin-top: -10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border-left: thin solid #041348;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="master-menu-right-wrapper">
  <div class="master-menu-right-item">Notification</div>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <div class="master-menu-right-item" id="add-menu" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Add</div>
    <div class="dropdown-menu master-menu-dropdown" aria-labelledby="add-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">New member</a>
      <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">New admin</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="master-menu-right-item">Setting</div>
  
  <div class="btn-group">
    <div class="master-menu-right-item master-menu-right-user">
        <div class="master-menu-right-user-font">Username</div>
    </div>
    <div class="master-menu-right-item" id="app-menu" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">User</div>
    <div class="dropdown-menu master-menu-dropdown" aria-labelledby="app-menu">
      <label>Welcome</label>
      <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">App 1</a>
      <div class="btn-group" role="group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mr-5">Save</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Edit profile</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Here is an example with boostrap 4 and font awesome.

> Note:display it at full screen to force the desktop view

Hope it helps.

```css
body {
    /*padding-top: 20px;*/
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <title>Multilingual Menu in Navbar Template for Bootstrap</title>
        <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flag-icon-css/3.1.0/css/flag-icon.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light rounded">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExample09" aria-controls="navbarsExample09" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExample09">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="dropdown09" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-us"> </span> English</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown09">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#fr"><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-fr"> </span>  French</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#it"><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-it"> </span>  Italian</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#ru"><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-ru"> </span>  Russian</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <!-- second drop down-->
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="dropdown10" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="fa fa-plus-square"> </span> </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown10">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#m"><span class="fa fa-minus-square"> </span></a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#check"><span class="fa fa-check"> </span> </a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-md-0">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
        <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```